# Replacing string in file Unix

Tags: linux, string, unix, replace, sed

I have a text file `file1.txt` on Unix. I'd like to produce another file `file2.txt`, in which I replace all occurrences of `apple-pie` with `apple_pie`. What command can I use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `sed` to do a global substitution on `file1.txt` and redirect the output to `file2.txt`:

```
sed 's/apple-pie/apple_pie/g' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` has better performance than `awk` but both will work for this search and replace. [Reference](https://davidlyness.com/post/the-functional-and-performance-differences-of-sed-awk-and-other-unix-parsing-utilities)

If you put the commands in a script (e.g., ksh, sh) then here is the syntax:

```
awk '{gsub(/apple-pie/,"apple_pie");print}' "file1.txt" > "file2.txt"
sed -e 's/apple-pie/apple_pie/g' "file1.txt" > "file2.txt"
```